Updgrading to Ubuntu24.04 messed up my laptop. How to get back to Ubuntu 22 graphics mode?
My Ubuntu system is messed up after trying to upgrade to Ubuntu24 from Ubuntu 22. I can log into the non-graphics mode. How to get to the graphics mode?
Tried to use the command:
sudo --configure -a
It failed. How do I proceed?

This question is similar to: Failed update to 24.04. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is similar to: How to fix broken 24.04.1 LTS upgrade which is missing necessary software?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is similar to: Switching between virtual console (tty) and GUI. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I started from the thread you talked about. The first command failed sudo apt update. I get errors as "Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.com', 'security.ubuntu.com', 'download.docker.com'.
